# How to initialize boost::random::discrete_distribution using std::vector?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, vector, boost-random

I would like to initialize `boost::random::discrete_distribution` with an `std::vector<double>`.

My problem is that if I initialize it with an array, like in the official example:

```
double probabilities[] = {
    0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1
};
boost::random::discrete_distribution<> dist(probabilities);
```

then it works perfectly.

However if I initialize it with a `std::vector`, then it behaves like if it has only one element with probability 1.0.

Can you tell me what is the right way of initializing a `boost::random::discrete_distribution<>` with a vector?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The class seems to have a constructor that [takes an iterator range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/random/discrete_distribution.html#boost.random.discrete_distributionconstruct-copy-destruct). This would be used with a vector like this:

```
std::vector<double> probs = ...;
boost::random::discrete_distribution<> dist(probs.begin(), probs.end());
```

Comment: do you know how to solve this? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013802/how-to-set-a-vector-of-discrete-distribution-c ) It is almost the same, but with a vector of distributions.