# How to set a vector of "discrete_distribution" c++

Tags: c++, vector, random

I'm trying to make a simulation of something like a Markov chain
and using discrete_distribution to simulate the change of state s_i to s_j.
But of course, this is a Matrix, not a vector.
So I try.

```
std::vector <uint16_t> v {{...},
                          {...},
                           ...
                          {...},};

std::vector <std::discrete_distribution <uint16_t> > distr(n, std::distribution <uint16_t> (v.begin(), v.end()) );
```

but this doesn't work.

**note: if I try just 1 vector, this is a vector of uint16_t works**

```
// CHANGE v by v[0]
std::vector<std::discrete_distribution <uint64_t>> distr(1, std::discrete_distribution <uint64_t> (vecs[0].begin(), vecs[0].end()));
```

based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904132/how-to-initialize-boostrandomdiscrete-distribution-using-stdvector)

I know that

```
std::vector <std::discrete_distribution <uint16_t> > distr(n, std::distribution <uint16_t> (v.begin(), v.end()) );
```

is not correct, but I say about the change v1 to v. to demonstrate that is possible use a vector of discrete distributions

Comment: Instead of creating these throw-away vectors called `v1` and so on, why not initialize the nested vector in one shot?

Comment: Because I did not know how to do it. But with the answer below now I know.

Comment: It's a pretty simple thing, and Vittorio explains it well. Is this question primarily about that, or is there still a problem with the `discrete_distribution` part?

Comment: the main issue is the **discrete_distribution** part and is not solved.

Comment: @tadman I post an answer, but I want to know if there is an "easy" way to do it, without creating a template, and initialize the distribution in the declaration.

Answer (score 5):

You can use *list initialization* to initialize nested vectors. E.g.:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}
};
```

Comment: Be aware that the list initialization will still create temporaries. See [The cost of std::initializer_list](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/the-cost-of-stdinitializer_list/)

Answer (score 2):

I find a way to do it like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904132/how-to-initialize-boostrandomdiscrete-distribution-using-stdvector)

using this template

```
template<typename T>
void set_distributions(std::vector< std::discrete_distribution <T> > &distr,  const std::vector< std::vector<T> > &vecs){
  for (uint64_t i = 0; i < vecs.size(); ++i) {
    distr.push_back( std::discrete_distribution <uint64_t> (vecs[i].begin(), vecs[i].end()) );
  }

}
```

and with this function, when you have emptied vectors of distributions

```
std::vector<std::discrete_distribution <uint64_t>> distr;
  set_distributions(distr, vecs);
```

Comment: Your code can use `std::transform` along with `std::back_inserter`: https://godbolt.org/g/DcxeUv

Comment: Is it possible using just one line? like `std::discrete_distribution<unsigned> dist(v.begin(), v.end());` I know... that a want all with just one line and its absurd but.. I need ask absurd questions to learn. like genetic algorithm with random mutations.

Comment: Actually, since you are basically using an out-parameter, it may be better to just [directly return the result, rather than take a non-const reference](https://godbolt.org/g/okm2fg)

Comment: I can't think of a one-liner for it. The standard containers and algorithms are made to be general, and this is kind-of a more specific case. Unfortunately, `std::discrete_distribution` isn't constructable directly from a container or this would be possible, but as it is, there is no way to do it in one line that I can see

Comment: [This](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jYBvQmAUZoQYMfX3) is the closest to a one-liner I could come up with, using boost.