# Why does c++ initialise a std::vector with zeros, but not a std::array?

Tags: c++, vector

Isn't it a waste of time to initialize a vector with zeros, when you don't want it?

I try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

#define SIZE 10

int main()
{
#ifdef VECTOR

  std::vector<unsigned> arr(SIZE);

#else

  std::array<unsigned, SIZE> arr;

#endif // VECTOR

  for (unsigned n : arr)
    printf("%i ", n);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

and I get the output:

with vector

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -D VECTOR test.cpp -o test && ./test 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

with an array

```
g++ -std=c++11  test.cpp -o test && ./test 
-129655920 32766 4196167 0 2 0 4196349 0 1136 0
```

And I also try with clang++

So why zeros? And by the way, could I declare a vector without initializing it?

Comment: They were designed that way many years apart, so maybe the thinking changed. `std::array` follows "you don't pay for what you don't need" better than `std::vector`.

Comment: `std::vector`: Because of the defaulted constructor parameter see (2) in: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector  _"Constructs the container with count copies of elements with value value."_

Comment: @RichardCritten That isn't saying *why*, it just says it is so in different words.

Comment: It would if you were to initialize the array `std::array<...> arr{};`

Comment: @juanchopanza yes it does default initialised with `unsigned()` is default initialised with `0`.  If you don't want default initialisation don't give a size and call `reserve` to get initialised space.  All the (8) constructors are consistent in that they value (or copy) initialise the vector.

Comment: @RichardCritten but... also is a destructive reading, right? if you print, you don't get the last values, you print an empty char

Comment: @RichardCritten Not sure if you were trying to answer my comment or someone else's. What I meant is that cppreference states the mandated behaviour as per the standard. It does not state why vector was designed to do this, against one of the design philosophies of C++. Also, `unsigned()` is not default initialization, it is value initialization.

Comment: @juanchopanza lets go to the time machine, you say that don't use the default could be a better philosophy? that could be a better standard? If that was because the reason that gives Justin below, that says why is a better standard/philosophy, right...?

Comment: @MoisesRojo The design philosophy I refer to is "you don't pay for what you don't need". So if you don't need a zero-initialized array (consider vector a dynamic array) then why pay for it? Standard C++ doesn't give you an alternative for `std::vector`, but it does for `std::array`. I think it is a design flaw, but maybe it was too hard to implement non-zeroing of builtin types back in the early days of C++.

Comment: ¡perfect answer! I will ever remember **you don't pay for what you don't... want/ask** But now the question is... Why not in a new c++xx standard? just compatibility?

Comment: It is possible to do exactly what you want, but the method is arcane. I posted an answer that shows how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have some class:

```
class MyClass {
    int value;

public:
    MyClass() {
        value = 42;
    }
    // other code
};
```

`std::vector<MyClass> arr(10);` will default construct 10 copies of `MyClass`, all with `value = 42`.

But suppose it didn't default construct the 10 copies. Now if I wrote `arr[0].some_function()`, there's a problem: `MyClass`'s constructor has not yet run, so the invariants of the class aren't set up. I might have assumed in the implementation of `some_function()` that `value == 42`, but since the constructor hasn't run, `value` has some indeterminate value. This would be a bug.

That's why in C++, there's a concept of [object lifetimes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime). The object doesn't exist before the constructor is called, and it ceases to exist after the destructor is called. `std::vector<MyClass> arr(10);` calls the default constructor on every element so that all the objects exist.

It's important to note that `std::array` is somewhat special, since it is [initialized following the rules of aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array#Member_functions). This means that `std::array<MyClass, 10> arr;` also default constructs 10 copies of `MyClass` all with `value = 42`. However, for non-class types such as `unsigned`, the values will be indeterminate.

---

There is a way to avoid calling all the default constructors: [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve). If I were to write:

```
std::vector<MyClass> arr;
arr.reserve(10);
```

The vector would allocate its backing array to hold 10 `MyClass`s, and it won't call the default constructors. But now I can't write `arr[0]` or `arr[5]`; those would be out-of-bounds access into `arr` (`arr.size()` is still 0, even though the backing array has more elements). To initialize the values, I'd have to call [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

```
arr.push_back(MyClass{});
```

This is often the right approach. For example, if I wanted to fill `arr` with random values from `std::rand`, I can use [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) along with [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
std::vector<unsigned> arr;
arr.reserve(10);
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(arr), 10, std::rand);
```

It's also worth noting that if I already have the values I want for `arr` in a container, I can just pass the `begin()/end()` in with the constructor:

```
std::vector<unsigned> arr{values.begin(), values.end()};
```

Comment: I'm surprised this got selected, because it begs the question "why doesn't `std::array` behave like this? Why can't `std::vector` behave like `std::array`? And that question sounds pretty much like what OP is asking.

Comment: @juanchopanza That's true, but I'm not sure I want to go into that in this answer. I intended to give the OP some intuition on why `std::vector` behaves in this way.

Comment: Question... "Why...?" R: Because vector call the default constructor, It's implicit (or I think) that array don't call it, that solve the question

Comment: BTW @Justin Do you know how to initialize a vector n-dimensions with `beginend` (is `begin()/end()` in emacs)? like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013802/how-to-set-a-vector-of-discrete-distribution-c/48740542#48740542)

Comment: @juanchopanza Thinking a bit more on it, I edited to include a short explanation for why `std::array` behaves the way it does. The behavior is indeed odd given only the explanation I gave before

Comment: @MoisesRojo Usually I would recommend using `std::vector<unsigned> matrix` even for multidimensional things. Instead, use a wrapper type, or use a helper function such as `index_from_2d(int x, int y, int width, int height) { return y * width + x; }`. Then you'd write `matrix[index_from_2d(x, y)]` to access elements. This is much more efficient.

Comment: This answer does not address the question. Why is the behavior different for *primitive* types? Why does `vector<int> x(100)` zero initialize but not `array<int, 100> x` does not?

Answer (score 5):

The more common way to declare a vector is without specifying the size:

```
std::vector<unsigned> arr;
```

This doesn't allocate any space for the vector contents, and doesn't have any initialization overhead. Elements are usually added dynamically with methods like `.push_back()`. If you want to allocate memory  you can use `reserve()`:

```
arr.reserve(SIZE);
```

This doesn't initialize the added elements, they're not included in the `size()` of the vector, and trying to read them is undefined behavior. Compare this with

```
arr.resize(SIZE);
```

which grows the vector and initializes all the new elements.

`std::array`, on the other hand, always allocates the memory. It implements most of the same behaviors as C-style arrays, except for the automatic decay to a pointer. This includes not initializing the elements by default.

Comment: serious? I think almost ever you will use `size()`, and that means you need to lose the time of initializing the vector with zeros, yes or yes. right?. Because yeah `push_back()` give a defined behaviour but... I don't want use `push_back()`?

Comment: for example, how can I do something like use std::iota in a range [1, 10], without initializing the vec, and using a std or a boost function?

Comment: @MoisesRojo: Like `generate_n(back_inserter(v), 10, []{ static int x = 7; return x++; });` maybe

Answer (score 5):

The default allocator is doing the zero-initialization. You can use a different allocator that does not do that. I wrote an allocator that uses default construction rather than initialization when feasible.  More precisely, it is an allocator-wrapper called `ctor_allocator`. Then I define a `vector` template.

`dj:vector<unsigned> vec(10);` does exactly what you want.  It's an `std::vector<unsigned> (10)`  that is not initialized to zeros.

```
--- libdj/vector.h ----
#include <libdj/allocator.h>
#include <vector>

namespace dj {
template<class T>
    using vector = std::vector<T, dj::ctor_allocator<T>>;
}

--- libdj/allocator.h  ----
#include <memory>

namespace dj {

template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
    class ctor_allocator : public A 
    {
        using a_t = std::allocator_traits<A>;
    public:
        using A::A; // Inherit constructors from A

        template <typename U> struct rebind 
        {
            using other =
                ctor_allocator
                <  U, typename a_t::template rebind_alloc<U>  >;
        };

        template <typename U>
        void construct(U* ptr)
            noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<U>::value) 
        {
            ::new(static_cast<void*>(ptr)) U;
        }

        template <typename U, typename...Args>
        void construct(U* ptr, Args&&... args) 
        {
            a_t::construct(static_cast<A&>(*this),
                ptr, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Yeah! Actually, I don't know why on my computer don't run, but in another, it runs perfectly.

Comment: [link] (https://wandbox.org/permlink/Pjkd0FlByO13k8km) Here works, but In my fedora 27, gcc 7.3 don't works

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Comments are not for solving programming problems.Perhaps my code is using a C++11 feature not supported by GCC 7.3. I do not  use GCC or know anything about it.  If you can't figure it out, post it as a new question.

Comment: How does it not work in GCC? Doesn't compile? Crashes? If it compiles and does not crash, it is almost certainly working.  It is quite possible that the vector memory will occasionally already contain zeros "by accident."

Comment: @Lightness -  It's all legit.

Comment: @JiveDadson: Are you sure? Because if it gives completely different results in GCC than your compiler (Visual Studio?) then it seems to me either your program has UB, or it relies on a vendor extension. A compiler bug is not out of the question, but if your code is "all legit" and uses only 7-year old language features then it is unlikely.

Comment: @Lightness - Yes I am sure. Moises has not said what the results are that he's getting on his machine. Syntax error? Crash? He has not said. It works on that wandbox link when you select GCC C++11.

Comment: the program compiles and doesn't crash, but initialize the vector with zeros. And actually in **wandbox** if the vector has a size (75 >=) dj::vector initialize the vector with zeros.

Comment: In my PC, doesn't matter the size, initialize the vector with zeros.

Comment: Well, the allocator is not doing (or re-doing) the initialization to zeros. Just because memory contains zeros does not mean they were put there when the vector was constructed.  Probably the OS clears process memory at the beginning, and your test code is using memory that has never been used since the process started.  The reason the Wandbox version has zeros for 75 and up but not lower is undoubtedly that when you allocate a small amount you are getting memory that has been used before, but not so when you allocate the larger amount.